# What is the most efficient way to work with multiple subelements?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I'm working on user management in python. I have an 'user_groups' array of maps where each element contains a key that has the name of the map and the value is an array of hosts where the group should be provisioned.

```
user_groups:
  robots: "test_server1,test_server2"
  developers: "test_server3,test_server4"
  tests: "test_server5"
```

I also have a `user_names` array where each element contains a map that contains details such as the username of the person, groups in which that person should be associated with, as well as any additional hosts the user should be associated with.

```
user_names:
  - username: mohamed
    group:
      - robots
      - tests
    hosts:
      user:
        - test_server4
```

Up until this point, our ansible playbook has been running on all hosts, and add users to hosts only if they were associated to the host either via groups, or by the hosts.user defined per user. This has been facilitated by subelement looping. As an example:

```
- name: If user is not associated with this host via groups or item.hosts.user, then ensure user is absent from host and remove user's home directory.
  become: true
  user:
    state: present
    name: "{{ item.0.username }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ user_names }}"
    - group
    - flags:
      skip_missing: true
  when: (item.0.hosts is defined and item.0.hosts.user is defined and inventory_hostname in item.0.hosts.user) or (inventory_hostname in user_groups.{{ item.1 }} ))
```

This has been working fine, but now I have a requirement to ensure that the user is absent on all hosts of which it is not associated. The primary use-case here being a user that undergoes a groups/user.hosts change but they will still exist on servers that are no-longer associated.

If I try the same block of code I posted above, but inverse the `when` condition and change `state` to `absent`, it does not work due the nature of looping; when running the task on a particular host, we loop through each server listed in groups. Not every iteration will match the `inventory_hostname`, so ansible will pre-emptively remove the user even if the association would be matched in a later iteration.

I think I'm trying to find out how to run a tasks only if all iterations of a loop match a condition. Or perhaps there is a more elegant way to solve a problem.

Expected result:

Map user to two group. Run ansible to have users provisioned on the hosts included in the groups.

Remove one group from the user. Run ansible and expect to have the user removed from the hosts it is no longer associated with.

I've tried nested `subelements`, using `product` jinja filter, `unions` but can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your comment, I understand better what you're trying to do.  Here's a different approach: build a unified list of hosts on which the users should exist.

Let's start with this sample data (I went with dictionaries for both existing variables this time):

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    user_groups:
      robots: [host0, host2]
      developers: [host0]
      tests: [host2]

    user_names:
      bob:
        group:
          - robots
          - tests
        hosts:
          - host0
      alice:
        group:
          - developers
        hosts:
          - host1
```

Now for each user, we will a unified list of the hosts on which they should be defined:

```
---
    # Just set a default value for user_hosts to avoid a bunch of
    # calls to the |default filter in the following expression.
    - set_fact:
        user_hosts: {}

    - set_fact:
        user_hosts: >-
          {{ user_hosts|combine({
          item.key:
          (
          item.value.hosts|default([])
          + user_groups|json_query('[{}][]'.format(','.join(item.value.group)))
          )|unique
          }) }}
      loop: "{{ user_names|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        var: user_hosts
```

This will produce:

```
ok: [host0] => {
    "user_hosts": {
        "alice": [
            "host1", 
            "host0"
        ], 
        "bob": [
            "host0", 
            "host1", 
            "host2"
        ]
    }
}
```

`alice` is defined on `host1` because that is explicitly declared in `user_names`.  She is defined on `host0` because she is a member of the `developers` group.

`bob` ends up defined on all three hosts in this example: `host0` because that is declared explicitly in `user_names`, and `host1` and `host2` because of his membership in the `robots` and `tests` groups.

Once you have this list, creating and deleting users is a simple matter of:

```
- name: create users
  debug:
    msg: "create user {{ item.key }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in item.value
  loop: "{{ user_hosts|dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"

- name: delete users
  debug:
    msg: "delete user {{ item.key }}"
  when: inventory_hostname not in item.value
  loop: "{{ user_hosts|dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
```

**Update**

If you group names aren't valid identifiers (e.g., they have whitespace or `-`, etc), you will need to quote them in the jmespath expression:

```
- set_fact:
    user_hosts: >-
      {{ user_hosts|combine({
      item.key:
      (
      item.value.hosts|default([])
      + user_groups|json_query('[{}][]'.format(
      ','.join(item.value.group|map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '"\1"'))
      ))
      )|unique
      }) }}
  loop: "{{ user_names|dict2items }}"
```

Here we're using the `regex_replace` filter and `map` to add quotes around each item in a list.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. 

Your restructuring of data, specifically changing comma-delimited strings into actual lists, is a great point.

In regards to your `delete users` example, it appropriately deletes users not associated with the host via `item.hosts` but I also need it to do verify that it is not associated with a host via `groups`. That means performing a lookup of the user's group in `user_groups` to get the associated hosts.

Comment: See my update, which I think addresses that particular problem.

Comment: You absolutely did. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! Since it seems this answer was helpful, you might want to mark it as accepted by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: When I implement the code, it seems to fail when the group name has a hyphen. Example 'dev-ops'. I know when not using variables you can solve this by putting the lookup key in quotes, but since we're already within a jinja expression quotes won't work in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: I do have an idea, and I've added it to the answer.